# Is it possible to force Clojure into using primitive types instead of their boxed versions?

Tags: java, clojure, division, boxing, divide-by-zero

I have a following sample of code:

```clj
(type (apply / [5.0 0]))
```

It throws an unexpected error - "Division By Zero" (expected behavior: return Inf)

Probably, it happens due to auto-boxing - can it be prevented?

Comment: What does this have to do with boxing at all? It's just a division by zero - which is undefined in math. Or am I missing something?

Comment: `(/ 5.0 0)` returns `##Inf`. I think OP is looking for some version of `apply` which returns the same result.

Comment: @JustanotherJavaprogrammer Java follows the IEEE 754 standard- see Exception handling, division by zero. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Exception_handling

Comment: Seems like a Clojure inconsistency (if not a bug).See https://clojure.atlassian.net/browse/CLJ-2244 and https://clojure.atlassian.net/browse/CLJ-1142

Comment: See [this answer with Clojure High Performance Programming suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20455645/2609980) and as also mentioned by dorab the [clj-commons/primitive-math](https://github.com/clj-commons/primitive-math) with "equivalents for every arithmetic operator and comparator that will give a reflection warning if it cannot compile down to a simple, predictable, unboxed mathematical operation".

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you just want to use a two argument division on doubles, the following might work.

```clj
user=> (apply (fn d2div [n d] (double (/ (double n) (double d)))) [5.0 0.0])
##Inf
```

If you go down this path, check out `clj-cmmons/primitive-math`.

Comment: Or with type hints: `(apply (fn [^double n ^double d] (/ n d)) [5.0 0.0])`

Answer (score -1):

How about

```
user=> (defmacro myapply [func args] `(~func ~@args))
#'user/myapply
user=> (myapply / [5.0 0])
##Inf
user=> (type (myapply / [5.0 0]))
java.lang.Double
```

I didn't know that `apply` behaves in such a different manner in Clojure.

Comment: This macro is useless. It only works for literal vectors, i.e. when you could have just written `(/ x y)` to begin with. It can't work for actual list variables, which is the point of apply.

Comment: What you mean with `list variables`? `(myapply / (5.0 0))` ? It works with it too.

Comment: @amalloy - this `myapply` works at least exactly as the OA expects it to behave ...

Comment: Ah I see - you mean an `apply` with evaluation of its arguments ...

Comment: Right. Anytime someone can call your macro, it must mean they have separate expressions for all N arguments already. If they have that, they could just write `(f x y z)` themselves, instead of `(myapply f [x y z])`.